# Optional String - View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot seem to get rid of the "optional" label in the following label. I've looked at different resources but couldn't figure out what to implement. Could you please show me where I'm mistaken?

[image: Cannot get rid of "Optional" label.]

```
class RatingViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var rateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rateView: EmojiRateView!


var ServicePoint: String!

 var ref:DatabaseReference?


let ratingTexts = [NSLocalizedString("Çok Kötü", value:"Very Bad", comment: ""), NSLocalizedString("Kötü", value:"Bad", comment:""), NSLocalizedString("Normal", value:"Normal", comment:""), NSLocalizedString("İyi", value:"Good", comment:""), NSLocalizedString("Çok iyi", value:"Very good", comment:""), NSLocalizedString("Mükemmel", value:"Perfect", comment:"")]


var newRateSyting = String("%.2f, %@")!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    rateView.rateValueChangeCallback = {(rateValue: Float!) -> Void in

        self.rateLabel?.text = String(format: self.newRateSyting, rateValue, self.ratingTexts[Int(rateValue)])

}
```

}

Comment: Look up "Optionals" in the Swift book by Apple and you will get the answer (and a lot more).

Comment: set "!" mark at end of the value make sure value will not be **nil** other wise you can use "?? "Value not found""

Comment: and name you variables, in your case `ServicePoint` starting with a lower case `servicePoint`. Not a must, but will make your life easier.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. What does `print(self.ratingTexts[Int(rateValue)])` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unwrap do as follow

```
let strRating =  "\(self.newRateSyting!)\(rateValue!)\(self.ratingTexts[Int(rateValue)]!)"
self.rateLabel?.text = strRating
```

**Example**

```
let value : String? = "4.7"
let review : String? = "very good"

let strRate = "\(value), \(review)"

print("Before unwrap")

print(strRate)

print("\n After unwrap")
let strRate2 = "\(value!), \(review!)"
print(strRate2)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

If you have **array of dict** , **array of array**, **dict of dict**, **dict of array**, then you have to unwrap like below:

```
(arr[index]["key"])! , (arr[index][index])!, (arr["key"]["key"])!, (arr["key"][index])!
```

Doesn't matter how much array or dict are complex, always follow above.

If you have still doubt then you can ask.

Comment: `String(format:, ...)` does *not* return an optional.

Comment: @MartinR Hope Now its OK. But whenever I used `String(format:,..)`, xcode  used this to avoid warning and it always returns optional. Can you pls explain me where i am wrong?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1417691-init does not return an optional, and actually I cannot reproduce OP's  problem with the provided code. So either I am overlooking something, or OP did not show the real code.